# FBSDKSharing Callback not returning results

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my iOS app, I have a Facebook share button, which opens up a FBSDKShareDialog:

```
-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{

    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.setShareURL];
    NSLog(@"facebook share url: %@", self.setShareURL);
    content.contentTitle= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@'s set", self.username];
    content.contentDescription=@"#spinturntable";

    FBSDKShareDialog *fbdialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]]){
        fbdialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
    }
    else {
        fbdialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser; //or FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic
    }
    fbdialog.shareContent = content;
    fbdialog.delegate = self;
    fbdialog.fromViewController = self;
    [fbdialog show];

}
```

If the user doesn't have the Facebook app, it opens up a window in Safari that asks them to log into Facebook.

If the user returns to my app without having logged in, the FBSDKSharing didCompleteWithResults callback gets called, but no results are returned:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
        NSLog(@"results: %@", results);
        NSLog(@"posted to facebook successfully!");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:@"Posted!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)  (delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });
}
```

However, if the user logs in and completes the post on Facebook, the callback also gets triggered with no results.

How do I differentiate so I only show the Posted alert if the user has actually posted to Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKSharingDelegate/#sharer:didCompleteWithResults:), `result` may be nil or empty. There is no guarantee that you will actually get something back that could be used by your app to confirm a share/post has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Looks FB changed something on Delegate
it when user share the delegate method will run with empty results, so if you are check something in this method to make sure that post posted correctly just remove it

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
```

and when user cancel share this method will run

```
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check in the delegate method `sharer:didCompleteWithResults:` if user has Facebook installed as [@Adam Eisfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31170011/2050181) suggested  :

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{

    // check if user has facebook app installed
    NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"];
    // there is no facebook app installed
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURL]){
        // facebook is not intalled check the keys
        if (results.allKeys.count !=0){
            // success you can get your post ID
        }else {
            // if resutlst.allKeys == 0 means user press Done button 
        }
    } else {
        // the share is successfully and facebook is installed
    }
}
```

and from iOS9.0 do not forget to add in your .plist file `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key (an array of strings) and add `fb` check [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/) post for more details.