# Facebook is returning anything when recompiling with iOS9

Tags: ios, facebook

I was having issue with iOS 8.4 compilation with Facebook SDK so I upgraded to Xcode 7.1 and using Facebook Sdk 4.6. I am following the below code for the login. It's giving me weird experiences, sometimes, it opens up SafariViewController, some times it opens both popup view and SafariViewController and sometimes it opens up only pop -up view.

In Any of the case, I try to login I don't get data in neither

> func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult
>   result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)

or in

> fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
>               if (error == nil)

I have followed and added the NSTransportExceptions too

> Codes

In ViewDidload I defined this

```
    fblogin.delegate = self
    fblogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
```

**fblogin is the loginButton**

```
@IBAction  func loginFb(sender:AnyObject)
{
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil { //Here we have to check that the set contains value or not
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    //fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
func getFBUserData(){
    NSLog("Called")
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.dict = result as! NSDictionary
                print(result)

                print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
                //NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as! String)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I was having issue with [Facebook is not returning data in didCompleteWithResult in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450138/facebook-is-not-returning-data-in-didcompletewithresult-in-ios-9/34450241#34450241) so I upgraded to Xcode 7

Comment: latest Facebook sdk is 4.8 did you try upgrading? try to follow fb getting started guide again to see if you missed any step

Comment: also try the parameter values without spaces e.g. "id,name,first_name,last_name,email"

Comment: I tried man however its opening with SafariViewController and after I Authenticate, its not closing the safariviewcontroller, not redirecting to the app..

Comment: Only in v4.5 it's redirecting to the app. After 4.6 it's using sfsafaricontroller. You can force using 4.5 to fix this

Comment: I'm going to sum up my comments as an answer please accept it if they helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a valid fields request they need to be without spaces e.g.
     "id,first_name,last_name,email"

About the switching to the Facebook app instead of showing SFSafariViewController you need to use any Facebook SDK before v4.6 in which they changed this

Comment: No..this is not causing the issue.. I just changed the class of FBSDKLoginButton to normal button and its working good with 4.5, I don't know...

Comment: This is what I said.. They changed the process in 4.6 so any SDK before will work for you

Comment: @KingBabar...Issue was just with FBSDKLoginButton and iOS 4.6. I changed the sdks version to 4.5 and then make my button a normal one not FBSDKLoginButton, it started working.