# iOS Facebook issue share link dialog, how to know User share success?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

When I choose X or Post success, `FBSDK` (version 4.26.0) always callback the same method (Device don't install Facebook app)

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
```

results is empty

How can I know it's user shared success or cancel it?

Please help me!

I'm using this method

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];

content.contentURL = URL;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: take a look at my solution maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067578/2050181

Answer (score 0):

I received the callback below:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results 
{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}
```

but the problem is when I choose X (To close the sharing interface) or Post (To share the content successfully), FBSDK (version 4.26.0) always callback same method didCompleteWithResults with results = empty

Noted: device doesn't install Facebook App