# sharing a post using FBSDK in iOS . i Got shared even when clicking cancel button

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

> sharing a post using FBSDK in iOS . i Got shared even when clicking cancel button it always calling didCompleteWithResults delegate method.

```
- (void) sharer: (id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:   (NSDictionary *)results
{
NSLog(@"results count %lu %@",(unsigned long)results.count,results);
  if(results)
{
         NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [cb setObject:@"0" forKey:@"alertid"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) userInfo:cb repeats:NO];
    [cb release];
}
else
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [cb setObject:@"2" forKey:@"alertid"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) userInfo:cb repeats:NO];
    [cb release];

}
}

 - (void) sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
 NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[cb setObject:@"2" forKey:@"alertid"];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) userInfo:cb repeats:NO];
[cb release];


}
```

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169965/facebook-ios-sdk-4-1-0-share-callback

Comment: i didn't get post id . if(results.count>0) it not enteredif part following lines but when i give if(result!=nil) it entered if part.

Comment: ok check two separate conditions

Comment: samecode for my another app its working correctly .... but here its not

Comment: oh , actually I cant find where the problem is occur